# How to use function do.call() efficiently?

Tags: r, do.call

I have many `dataframe` (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,....) in a list which have the same structure. When using `do.call()` to union all of them, it's very slow. Is there any method to combine them more efficiently? Thanks!

```
mylist<-list(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,....)
do.call(rbind, mylist)
```

Comment: can you give a little more detail, e.g. how many data frames (approximately) are you combining, and how big (how many rows/cols) are they (approximately)?

Comment: `do.call(rbind, mylist)` should be fast, so it's not clear why it is behaving poorly. Unfortunately we don't have your data, is there a way to make a reprex such that we can observe the slowdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(mylist)
```